# Is there a way to run a Mac command line operation in R Studio?

Tags: java, r, command-line

On a unix system, is there a way to call a command line code without leaving the RStudio IDE?

For instance, lets say I'm in working directory x which is not the same directory y as a java executable is located. Is there a way to run the java executable in y? There would be several command line options to select alongside the

`java Execute.java`

call. It would look more like

`java Execute.java input.txt output.txt options`

I apologize for the rough formatting here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `?system` also there is a terminal tab next to the console tab

Comment: You're completely right. Every time I had tried using system in the past I was unsuccessful because I wasn't putting the input in strings. With the combination of system and && to break up functions, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `system2` to invoke shell commands. `system2` is more portable and flexible then `system`. See the following for more information on how to use it: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html